# Trasnforming/Changing all variables at one go in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python & I'm looking to transform the variables in my data set. I have around 89 variables to be transformed & hence, transforming them one by one is tedious. I'm looking to transform 88 variables.

How do I go about doing this? One option I can think of is to create a list of all the columns of the data set & then call this list in the function I define.

Is there any other way?

Thank you,
Nimish

Comment: What format or data type is your dataset in? Is it a `numpy` array, for example, or something else? Can you show the code you would use to transform one variable?

Comment: the input is a csv file. What I'm attempting to do is to transform the input variables based on the output variable. The output variable is in the form of 1 & 0. The input variables range from 0 to 100. I want to apply a method which would populate the input variables to 1 when the output is 1 & the respective input variable is not zero.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a variable, how it is currently defined, and what change you would like done to it.

Comment: You need to provide us an example of what your csv looks like